# Check base sdk of library

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, static-libraries

For example I have somelib.a file. Is there any way on Mac OS to check static/dynamic library, against which base SDK it's linked and deployment SDK (e.g. 10.6 ... 10.8) 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Static libraries are not linked against anything, they are a simple archive of object files.  So the answer is no, as it doesn't make sense.

Comment: but static library can depend on dynamic library

Comment: Yeah of course, but that isn't enforced in the library file itself; instead you have to remember to link in whatever dependent libraries it requires.

Comment: it appears that if I create static lib in Mac OS 10.5 It also should work in 10.8 ?

Comment: @amplifier That depends on the code in the library; if it calls stuff no longer available in 10.8 it will run, but will crash.  Technically this is "working", just working very badly.

Comment: that's pretty much my problem. I built lib on 10.8 but it crashes on 10.7. I think I should set LDFLAGS and CFLAGS to build using 10.7 sdk?

Comment: @amplifier No, it won't (really) matter which SDK you use.  You need to figure out what code is breaking under 10.7.

Comment: Ok. Will find mac with 10.7 and debug it. But I think it uses some functions not available in 10.7. Thank you